# Simple C# or unityscript coding in Unity3d. Need to remove all distinct words from a nx2 array

Tags: string, split, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Sorry But I am very new to coding in Unity. I have an nx2 array as shown:

```
var questans = new String[10, 10];
questans[0,0]="Hey How's it going?";
questans[0,1]="You know me Just chillin'";
questans[1,0]="Hello there friend";
questans[1,1]="Well met to you too!";
questans[2,0]="I like chocolate pudding";
questans[2,1]="Good for you";
```

I need to basically write a for loop that can go across this array and give me an array that contains all the distinct words. Hence, the output should be: [Hey, How's, it, going.....]

I wrote a function to do this, but I am unable to split the string since Unity is giving my code some weird error with string.split:

I had written:

```
var ff:String [] // Temporary variable. I'm just testing for the first string questans[0,0]
ff=quesans[0,0].Split(" "[0]);
```

However, it gave me System.String[] as an output... even on iterating through ff.

Can someone please give me a way how I can possibly go across this whole array (I can iterate through it) and get every distinct word without having to manually write a for loop for it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing i'm going to tell you is that your variable "**questans**" is *not* "**quesans**". so "*ff=quesans....*" shouldn't work. Perhaps that is your problem? if not:

This is rather simple, actually.
What you had written is, in concept, a working piece of code.
Try this:

```
var ff: String[questans.Length]; //Returned string array
var linenumber = 0; //Current line, 0-index
var spacecount = 0; //Current space in current line, 0-index
foreach (var line in questans)
{
    foreach (var spaceSplit in line.Split(" "))
    {
        ff[linenumber, spacecount] =  spaceSplit[spacecount];
        spacecount++;
    }
    spacecount = 0;
    linenumber++;
}
```

In this piece of code, i'm nesting two foreach loops to catch each space within each line and return an array of arrays of lines, split by spaces.

Also, on a side note, when creating an array **questans** that i suggest you initialize it and assign it all in the same code-line. For array **questans** i'd do this:

```
var questans: String[10, 10] = [["Hey How's It Going?",
        "You know me Just chillin'"],
        ["Hello there friend",
        "Well met to you too!"],
        ["I like choclate pudding",
        "Good for you"]];
```

**EDIT**:

*If you want to get through the entire array without a loop, then i'm at a loss. Sorry but i doubt there is such a method.*

Comment: Oh No.. I meant.. I know how to loop through.. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use **Distinct** method for your array collection, as shown here.
[Distinct value 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx)
[Distinct value 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)

This will help you and you do not need any sticky loops.

Comment: But I need the words in the string. This'll just give me the distinct string tuples right?